# Trick/Fake proof of 2x2=5 ; algebraic form

Tags: arithmetic, fake-proofs

Just ran into "algebraic proof" that 2x2=5 on youtube. They didn't hide that it was a trick. Can't find where is the mistake.

Let a=4, b=5, c=1

1. c=b-a                   /multiply by (b-a)
2. c(b-a) = (b-a)(b-a)     /distribute
3. cb-ca = b^2-2ab+a^2     /subtract a^2
4. cb-ca-a^2 = b^2-2ab     /add ab
5. ab+cb-ca-a^2 = b^2-ab   /subtract cb
6. ab-ca-a^2 = b^2-ab-cb   /factor a and b respectively
7. a(b-c-a)=b(b-a-c)       /divide by (b-a-c)
8. a=b                     /substitute with given value
9. 4=5

Comment: You can't divide by $b-a-c = 5-4-1 = 0$. Theese kind of proofs always end up with a $0$-division and you can say that this is a good motivation you can't divide a number by $0$!

Comment: @Gabrielek Indeed: my first though was "where have they divided by zero". It is quite well hidden here. You should put that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @MarkBennet Okay, but I think an answer to this kind of questions is a way to get free +1 and they are not hard worked ahah

Comment: @Gabrielek I feel the same quite often, but I have more reputation than you do. But the point of the site is to have questions and answers, and if answers appear in comments (a) the person who comments gets no credit and (b) very often someone else grabs the points. Most irritating to me are the answers which fill out hints prematurely and save the person who asked the question from having to think. Your answer still gives OP the job of thinking "how/where did that happen?"

Comment: Thank you for understanding my point of view. I totally agree

Comment: "Theese kind of proofs always end up with a 0-division..."  That's simply not true!   The really sophisticated fake proofs that $1=0$ play with complex exponentials, or integrate across a singularity. :P

Comment: @Иваныч  I have cast the fourth (and, in this case, final) vote to close this question for "lacking context".  Please read the guide on [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/), paying special attention to the section on context.  Please also read the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) and use the information provided there to clean up your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't divide by $b−a−c=5−4−1=0$. Theese kind of proofs always end up with a $0$-division and you can say that this is a good motivation you can't divide a number by $0$!

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it. Thanks. I did check it numerically but not the last step. Gee.

Comment: Basically, it only proves that in c=b-a, a could be equal b? If we drop the numeric values.

Comment: It does not prove nothing. $c=b-a$ is trivial since we choose $a,b,c$ such that $1=5-4$.